# "Missing \cr inserted", but it looks to me like it's already there!

Tags: plain-tex

I'm trying to create a Plain TeX macro for typesetting two-column proofs with automatic step-numbering and step cross-referencing; currently, the "best" I have is:

```
\newcount\stepno
\def\twocols#1{%
 \everycr={\advance\stepno by 1}
 \def\mkstep##1{%
    \expandafter \ifx \csname##1step\endcsname \relax%
       \expandafter\edef\csname##1step\endcsname{\the\stepno}%
    \else \message{^^JWarning: attempt to define ##1 more than once^^J^^J}%
      \stepref{##1}%
    \fi}%
 \def\stepref##1{%
    \expandafter \ifx \csname##1step\endcsname \relax {\tt[##1]}%
    \else \csname##1step\endcsname%
    \fi}%
 $$\vbox{
  \offinterlineskip
  \halign{
   \strut\the\stepno. ##\hfil & \vrule ##\hfil\cr%
   %\noalign{\hrule\smallskip}
   #1 \cr
  }
 }$$
}

\twocols{
 \mkstep{A} $(p\to q)\land (q\to r)$ & premise \cr
 \mkstep{B} $p\to (q\land(q\to r))$ & \stepref{A}, logic07 \cr
 $p\to r$ & \stepref{B}, {\it modus ponens}
}

\bye
```

Unfortunately, trying to typeset this yields the following inexplicable error:

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./twocols02.tex
! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text>
                \cr 
<to be read again>
                   }
\twocols ... ##\hfil & \vrule ##\hfil \cr #1 \cr }
                                                   }$$ 
l.28 }

? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on twocols02.log.
```

Why is it claiming there's a missing `\cr` where there clearly appears to be one?  I've tried removing the `\cr` from the macro definition and adding a `\cr` to the end of the macro argument, replacing the `\cr` with `\crcr`, removing the newline between the two closing braces there, using two `\cr`s, dispensing with the macro and trying to typeset what it should expand to, and various combinations thereof, yet I keep getting this error, and I'm out of ideas.  What's going on?

(Also, I suspect that using `\mkstep` the way I am will cause the resulting reference macros to be scoped to just the column in which `\mkstep` is used, rather than to the whole `\twocols`; is there a way to fix that without making the reference macros global?)

Comment: There's no point in defining `\mkstep` and `\stepref` inside `\twocols`, as their definition doesn't depend on the argument to `\twocols`. Of course defining `\Astep` as you do in a cell will leave it undefined elsewhere, so `\xdef` is needed. I'd also put `\relax` before the starting conditional in the definitions of `\mkstep` and `\stepref`

Comment: In order to have unique macros you could use another counter that is stepped at each call of `\twocols`, say `\csname ##1@\the\schemecount@step\endcsname`.

Comment: @egreg: no point unless you call it inside a group, right?

Comment: @morbusg If one wanted that `\mkstep` were available only in the argument to `\twocols` then a group should be opened just at the beginning of the definition of `\twocols`. In the OP's example, `\mkstep` remains defined just to be redefined in the same way at a second call of `\twocols`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 \everycr={\noalign{\global\advance\stepno by 1}}%
```

you are inserting tokens after the last explicit `\cr` so need to make sure they don't start a new row.